# WSDL to java Conversion for android

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to convert wsdl to java and same can be used in Android?

Thanks in advance.

--
Ramu

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/). This will allow you to generate the necessary stubs from your wsdl file for the android platform.